# Why can't play video (1920x1080) on Nexus 4?

Tags: android, android-camera

My code setting to create a Video (1920x1080) by my Camera App on Nexus 4:

```
mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P));
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());
mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());
```

But i can't play this video on Target Nexus 4:
My code open video by standard App of Android:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();                        
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File file = new File(strFileName);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
    startActivity(intent);
```

It show message: `Can't play this video.`
(This video play ok by window media)

I test on N-07D is Ok, but on Nexus 4 was error `Can't play this video.`

Why can't play video(1920x1080) on Nexus 4?(Althought It can create a video(1920x1080))

Comment: What is the format of video ?

Comment: format of video is  MP4

Comment: What happens if you just use intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file)); ?

Comment: The video is too large for that device, if you change that video size to 960x540 or 480x270 you should be ok.